# How to find Vo in a circuit with two voltage sources

Tags: voltage, passive-networks

I do not know how to find Vo in this circuit. According to my notes about how to take node voltage, I get

0 = Va + 6.857 V + 0V

Vo = Va

But that doesn't sound right. And I get a different answer using mesh, then using

Vo = V Across the 4k resistor

[image]

I would really appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: Hint: one of your sources is connected directly across \$v_o\$, so nothing else in the circuit matters.

Comment: Also, you give an equation using the term \$v_a\$, but you never said what \$v_a\$ represents. If we knew that, we might be able to point out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

KVL is a law, not a suggestion. Trust Kirchhoff, trust your instincts. If you are getting a different answer using mesh analysis then we should take a look at your equations.